# If Devs And QA work together in the same office. Is that considered a DevOps practice?

Tags: software-development, agile

I work as a DEV in the same office with the QA. We communicate together, the QA finds functional errors which are directly communicated to me in order to update or fix the code. Is that considered a DevOps Practice?

Comment: It sounds like you're actually trying to achieve a different goal than just having the answer to this question?

Comment: I think @Cronax may be suggesting that DevOps are trying to do a bit of "empire building" by taking over QA, just because they sit nearby.

Comment: @Cronax I have no goal. I don't want to  control the universe. It's just had a stupid thought while trying to understand Devops. Stupid thoughts are cool sometimes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DevOps is the contraction of Software (Dev)lopment and IT (Op)eration(s). It's more about joining devs and those that control their environment (choice of tools, CI configurations, etc.) ideally as a single team.

QA is not part of the DevOps equation, so **No**

What you are describing is more akin to Agile practices, or more elementary collaboration on a task.

Comment: **or more elementary collaboration on a task.** is what is happening exactly.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Glad I asked. I was going for it

Comment: Well... OK so having crossfunctional teams (more than just "being in the same office") is indeed Agile, as a core agile practice is to put all the requisite skills on a team to deliver value. ref: https://www.scaledagileframework.com/agile-teams/.  This should also include operations, hence DevOps, but the primary practice of crossfunctional teams is Agile.